# iOS app weird crash in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, background, crash

I need help.

I'm working on an old iOS app written in Objective-c. It was released in 2014 and now I have migrated the project to Xcode 8. After migration everything works as expected except weird crash when app is in background(not immediately but after some time). It's hard to debug because crash occurs only when device is disconnected from Xcode. I have checked device logs and it seems like it's core data crash:

```
Incident Identifier: BDD70C46-6573-44A7-85AB-620E6FBA207F
CrashReporter Key:   c04f591f9e0cc9d1991ce10e33ebcabd56affbe6
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,4
Process:             myApp [17746]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/878DB803-1DA5-46D7-8B50-655D43A5C28D/myApp.app/myApp
Identifier:          com.example.myApp
Version:             2 (1.0.2)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.example.myApp [16959]


Date/Time:           2017-09-19 14:34:57.1435 +0300
Launch Time:         2017-09-19 14:31:38.0853 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace <0xF>, Code 0x8badf00d
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: SQLQueue 0x100724310 for myApp.sqlite
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018f36d818 0x18f361000 + 51224
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018f36c9a4 0x18f361000 + 47524
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018f36c9a4 0x18f361000 + 47524
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018f36c2c4 0x18f361000 + 45764
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x000000018f36bf24 0x18f361000 + 44836
5   CoreData                        0x000000019113e0b0 -[NSSQLiteConnection prepareSQLStatement:] + 468
6   CoreData                        0x000000019125f178 -[NSSQLiteConnection updateRow:forRequestContext:] + 492
7   CoreData                        0x0000000191307f28 _writeChangesForSaveRequest + 1128
8   CoreData                        0x0000000191309584 _executeSaveChangesRequest + 388
9   CoreData                        0x00000001912ff5f0 -[NSSQLSaveChangesRequestContext executeRequestUsingConnection:] + 44
10  CoreData                        0x00000001912170c4 __52-[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:]_block_invoke + 256
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100455a10 0x100454000 + 6672
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001004625bc 0x100454000 + 58812
13  CoreData                        0x0000000191216f64 -[NSSQLDefaultConnectionManager handleStoreRequest:] + 208
14  CoreData                        0x00000001912d9824 -[NSSQLCoreDispatchManager routeStoreRequest:] + 272
15  CoreData                        0x000000019124475c -[NSSQLCore dispatchRequest:withRetries:] + 236
16  CoreData                        0x0000000191240578 -[NSSQLCore processSaveChanges:forContext:] + 200
17  CoreData                        0x0000000191144f10 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 724
18  CoreData                        0x000000019122384c __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 3492
19  CoreData                        0x000000019121c0f0 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeHeavyweightBlock:] + 276
20  CoreData                        0x0000000191144adc -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 408
21  CoreData                        0x000000019116597c -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 2548
22  myApp                   0x00000001000cd0dc 0x1000c0000 + 53468
23  myApp                   0x00000001000cbc24 0x1000c0000 + 48164
24  CoreLocation                    0x00000001970ee828 0x1970de000 + 67624
25  CoreLocation                    0x00000001970edfcc 0x1970de000 + 65484
26  CoreLocation                    0x00000001970e11d8 0x1970de000 + 12760
27  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee1930c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
28  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee18b28 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 288
29  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee16e1c __CFRunLoopRun + 1884
30  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ed46da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
31  GraphicsServices                0x00000001907b1074 GSEventRunModal + 100
32  UIKit                           0x0000000195001c9c UIApplicationMain + 208
33  myApp                   0x00000001000e4574 0x1000c0000 + 148852
34  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018dd5559c start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: BKSProcessAssertionClient
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de47224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de4709c mach_msg + 72
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010046d37c 0x100454000 + 103292
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010046d780 0x100454000 + 104320
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018df60edc xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 196
5   BaseBoard                       0x000000019095a944 -[BSXPCMessage sendSynchronouslyToConnection:error:] + 76
6   BaseBoard                       0x0000000190957148 -[BSBaseXPCClient _sendMessage:withReplyHandler:waitForReply:waitDuration:] + 436
7   AssertionServices               0x00000001909a17c4 -[BKSProcessAssertionClient _assertionQueue_sendEvent:forMessageType:responseHandler:] + 136
8   AssertionServices               0x00000001909a0f78 -[BKSProcessAssertionClient sendCreateAssertion:] + 108
9   AssertionServices               0x00000001909a0968 -[BKSProcessAssertion _clientQueue_acquireAssertion] + 312
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100455a50 0x100454000 + 6736
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100455a10 0x100454000 + 6672
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001004632e8 0x100454000 + 62184
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100459634 0x100454000 + 22068
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100465630 0x100454000 + 71216
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010046539c 0x100454000 + 70556
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2b100 _pthread_wqthread + 1096
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2acac start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x17013b6c0.events
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de47278 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010047f238 0x100454000 + 176696
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100467db8 0x100454000 + 81336
3   CoreLocation                    0x00000001970e1078 0x1970de000 + 12408
4   CoreLocation                    0x00000001970e6118 0x1970de000 + 33048
5   CoreLocation                    0x00000001970e5f18 0x1970de000 + 32536
6   CoreLocation                    0x0000000197131e88 0x1970de000 + 343688
7   CoreLocation                    0x000000019712e4f0 0x1970de000 + 328944
8   CoreLocation                    0x000000019712e414 0x1970de000 + 328724
9   CoreLocation                    0x000000019712fa80 0x1970de000 + 334464
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018df5f84c _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018df5d358 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 1448
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100455ae0 0x100454000 + 6880
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001004599d8 0x100454000 + 23000
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100463128 0x100454000 + 61736
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100458da0 0x100454000 + 19872
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100463128 0x100454000 + 61736
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100459634 0x100454000 + 22068
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100463128 0x100454000 + 61736
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100459634 0x100454000 + 22068
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000100464358 0x100454000 + 66392
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000010046c57c 0x100454000 + 99708
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2afbc _pthread_wqthread + 772
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2acac start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de47224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de4709c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee18e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee16ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ed46da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   Foundation                      0x000000018f861db4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x000000018f882b84 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x000000019598b830 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x000000018f95f318 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2d68c _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2d59c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2acb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2aca8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de47224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de4709c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee18e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee16ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ed46da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018f553df4 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 404
6   Foundation                      0x000000018f95f318 __NSThread__start__ + 996
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2d68c _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2d59c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2acb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  GAIThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de47224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de4709c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee18e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee16ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ed46da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   Foundation                      0x000000018f861db4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x000000018f8b6704 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   myApp                   0x0000000100120398 0x1000c0000 + 394136
8   Foundation                      0x000000018f95f318 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2d68c _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2d59c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2acb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2aca8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2aca8 start_wqthread + 0
```

But in major cases crash report looks like:

```
Incident Identifier: D5D6C3C6-7EB7-4E2C-901C-7203943BD722
CrashReporter Key:   c04f591f9e0cc9d1991ce10e33ebcabd56affbe6
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,4
Process:             myApp [17444]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/93AB2A15-0C65-47D5-BE24-FB298DC396E0/myApp.app/myApp
Identifier:          com.example.myApp
Version:             2 (1.0.2)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.example.myApp [16449]


Date/Time:           2017-09-19 12:41:45.3051 +0300
Launch Time:         2017-09-19 12:24:22.7861 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace <0xF>, Code 0x8badf00d
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de47224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de4709c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee18e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee16ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ed46da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   GraphicsServices                0x00000001907b1074 GSEventRunModal + 100
6   UIKit                           0x0000000195001c9c UIApplicationMain + 208
7   myApp                   0x0000000100031bb8 0x10000c000 + 154552
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018dd5559c start + 4

Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de47224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de4709c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee18e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee16ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ed46da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   Foundation                      0x000000018f861db4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x000000018f882b84 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x000000019598b830 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x000000018f95f318 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2d68c _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2d59c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2acb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 2 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de47224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de4709c mach_msg + 72
2   myApp                   0x000000010008d6a0 0x10000c000 + 530080
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2d68c _pthread_body + 240
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2d59c _pthread_body + 0
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2acb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de47224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de4709c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee18e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee16ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ed46da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018f553df4 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 404
6   Foundation                      0x000000018f95f318 __NSThread__start__ + 996
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2d68c _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2d59c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2acb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  GAIThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de47224 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018de4709c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee18e90 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ee16ae4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1060
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ed46da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   Foundation                      0x000000018f861db4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x000000018f8b6704 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   myApp                   0x000000010006d9dc 0x10000c000 + 399836
8   Foundation                      0x000000018f95f318 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2d68c _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2d59c _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2acb4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2aca8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2aca8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2aca8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2aca8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018df2aca8 start_wqthread + 0
```

Maybe someone had a similar issue and have some suggestions?

Comment: Do you have `Received memory warning` ??

Comment: When app is running and connected with xcode there is no memory warnings, but I can't debug whats happening when app runs without connection.

Comment: Can you simulate a memory warning ? to do that : Go to your simulator debug menu and click on "Simulate memory warnings"

Comment: Yes, -didReceiveMemoryWarning firing

Comment: there is no crash ?

Comment: What do you mean "major cases"? I don't understand when you get one crash report instead of the other.

Comment: @AliAbbas no crash

Comment: @TomHarrington Sometimes I get one, sometimes another. But everytime app crashes after few minutes for being in background and report says that crashed in foreground.

Comment: Based on the crash log it looks like you are writing to core data based on a core location change. Perhaps that happens in the background and you can't write to core data at the time so it hangs and is then killed by the watch dog. Do you have secure file access enabled?

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I have solved this issue by removing background task and allowing location manager for background updates. And special thanks for @clarus, your answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that's odd is that you say this happens in the background, but the crashes are happening when the app is in the foreground as far as the system is concerned:

```
Role:                Foreground
```

So, that's confusing.

Just wild guessing, I'd look at things like memory corruption/using released objects (especially if this is non-ARC code), async code like networking requests or timer callbacks jumping into released code, doing things like UI on a thread that's not the main thread (if you can run under Xcode 9, the runtime thread diagnostics will help a lot with this.) Even with Xc8, look at your project's scheme and the memory debugging options available under the Run configuration. Those could help.

Check out the running system log on the device. You don't need to be debugging with Xcode to see that. Just go to the Devices window and the system console will be near the bottom. You may need to reveal it. That system log may give a clue.

If you're using manual retain/release, double check any code that gets hit in the time frame of the crash. Keep in mind that those types of crashes happen after the problem occurs, so where you see the crash may have little bearing on where the actual problem is, and the crash location may fluctuate, especially on different devices.

Maybe diff the pre-Xcode 8 code and the current code to double-check any changes you've made. My guess is that you introduced a memory issue when updating the code for Xcode 8.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, just noticed the termination reason.

This may help:

> The exception code 0x8badf00d indicates that an application has been
>   terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. The application
>   took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events. One
>   common cause of this is doing synchronous networking on the main
>   thread. Whatever operation is on Thread 0: needs to be moved to a
>   background thread, or processed differently, so that it does not block
>   the main thread.

Make sure as you're going into the background you're not doing anything that will take a long time, use a background task if needed, and don't do anything like OpenGL calls from the background. Since the crash report says you're in the Foreground, I wonder if you're taking too long going into the background and Springboard is killing your app. The system log will confirm that.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will check background tasks. The case that app taking long going into the background seems reasonable. It was strange why report says that app crashed in foreground. But the strange thing is why the crash appears only when disconnected from xcode? And why previuos xcode version build was working fine?

Comment: @ArnoldasLiudžius When using Xcode, watchdog timers don't usually affect the app. Someone might be trying to debug why the app has stopped responding, for example, so it would be bad if the watchdog killed the app.